# problem in executing Stored procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a stored procedure:

```
create or replace procedure AAAAAA(
ID in dbms_sql.number_table,
Name in dbms_sql.varchar2s
)
is
 tableName varchar2(30) := 'QWERT_';
Begin
Forall k in 1...ID.COUNT SAVE EXCEPTIONS
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  'insert into ' || tableName || ID(k) ||   
' values (:1,:2)' using ID(k), NAME(k);
--EXCEPTION HANDLING CODE
End;
```

But , on compiling above code i am getting

> [Error] PLS-00801 (9: 5): PLS-00801:
>   internal error [*** ASSERT at file
>   pdw4.c, line  607; Unknown expression
>   Expr = 283.; AAAAAA_*FFF*_P__274784[9,
>   5]]. "tableName || ID(k) " table
>   already created before running this
>   procedure.

Any idea why i am getting this error.
Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The FORALL has to insert into the same table. It does a single PARSE and multiple BIND/EXECUTES. As such you can't use an array variable [ID(k)] to form your table name.

Comment: If i want to have such query then is there any workaround of it.